# lettrine in csquotes blockquote leaves empty space in subsequent paragraphs

Tags: csquotes, lettrine

I'm trying to put a big quotation mark as a lettrine in the opening of a blockquote.

This works, however if there are multiple paragraphs in the blockquote, the following paragraphs needlessly retain the space set aside for the lettrine resulting in ugly indentation (marked with red in the example).

I suspect that the `lines` option in the lettrine command sets some internal state that is not reset for the following paragraphs, unlike what is the case outside the blockquote environment.

[image: example]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\SetBlockEnvironment{quotation}

\def\quotelettrine{\textquotedblleft}
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{%
    \lettrine[lines=2, findent=.5em, nindent=0em]{\quotelettrine}{}%
    {\itshape#1}#2#3#4%
}

%%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\blockquote{\lipsum[2-3]}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need an additional pair of braces: `\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{{\lettrine[lines=2, findent=.5em, nindent=0em]{\quotelettrine}{}{\itshape#1}}#2#3#4}`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've done some tests and it seems to work only for the final paragraph (try changing the lipsum inside the quote to 2-4)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lettrine often conflicts with lists and `quotation`, `quote` are `list` environments.

The usual fix is to reset `\parshape` (with `\parshape=0` in the easy cases), but in your case you would need something like this:

```
 \blockquote{\lipsum[2]
 \par\parshape=1 \leftmargin \linewidth
 \lipsum[3-4]}
```

in order to reset `\leftmargin` and `\rightmargin` properly for the surrounding `quotation` environment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have tested and it works in my full document. I suppose it isn't possible to automatically insert this after the first paragraph? Thinking out loud, perhaps encasing it in an environment? Possibly with an option or something so it can be disabled if wrongly applied?

Comment: @meide Maybe `\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{{\lettrine[lines=2, findent=.5em, nindent=0em]{\quotelettrine}{}{\everypar{\parshape=1 \leftmargin \linewidth}\itshape#1}}#2#3#4}` works?

Comment: It does! thank you :)

Comment: I am not sure it is safe to overwrite `\everypar` in lists… but using `\everypar` to reset `\parshape` cleanly should be doable, I am experimenting about it; hopefully I might be able to release a new version of `\lettrine` solving this issue. Thanks to @meide for reporting and to @Robert for suggesting `\everypar`!

Comment: Fyi I have just uploaded to CTAN version 2.22 of the `lettrine` package which should fix the issue reported by @meide.